# The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>' Error is in expression

Tags: outputlink

Receiving below error in Apex:OutputLink

In my code Im trying to redirect to following dashboard Link.

```
    <a href="sfdcloginurl/apex/competencyDashboard?id={!accountList[0].Id}"   target="_blank">Solution Competency</a></td>
```

I have received below error. Below Line of code isnot present in my vf page:

```
 {!IF((round(account.of_VSP_CP__c,0)>0),true,false)}
```

From where this error is appearing???

> The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'
>
> Error is in expression `{!IF((round(account.of_VSP_CP__c,0)>0),true,false)}` in 
>     component `<apex:outputLink>`

```
   <td style="border: 1px solid #8D8E92;"><a href="sfdcloginurl/apex/competencyDashboard?id={!accountList[0].Id}"   target="_blank">Solution Competency</a></td>
```

Instead of providing org url,I had written sfdcloginurl

> This Error Occurs while re rendering to Target Page.In fw Links,it works fine.In few Links it works fine.

Comment: Please clarify where you are seeing this issue. Is it in the problems tab of the Developer Console?

Comment: No iam seeing the issue .after clicking anchor tag Link

Comment: So... the error occurs while rendering the target page?

Comment: Yes.You are right

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to use BLANKVALUE to check for a blank value:

```
{!round(blankvalue(account.of_VSP_CP__c,0),0)>0)}
```

The IF statement is not necessary, since you're just interested in a true/false value.

Comment: I have tried this code: but still im getting error {!(round(blankvalue(account.of_VSP_CP__c,0),0)>0)} @sfdcfox